# Shortcut to run SQL query in R-Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

R-Studio has the ability to connect to a SQL database. I can run the entire script I've written by either hitting the *preview* button or pressing `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`.

But how do I run only the current selection or a part of the script??

Answer (score -1):

You can run the selected code with `CTRL + Enter`. This will run code you have selected, or the current line.

There is also the option to define your own [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178?version=1.1.453&mode=desktop) in RStudio.

Comment: No, this does not work. It works in R scripts, but not in SQL scripts. I also don't find it in the shortcut list. :/

Comment: Can you add som example code? E.g. how is your connection set up?

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with the query or with the connection. Both work fine. Even if I posted the query. What would you do with it, since you don't have access to this very database??